# What does it do when we defines USER in docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have some confusion related to user defined in Dockerfile.

**User defined in Dockerfile:** Purpose of user is to run the command defined in CMD statement with that user.

**So my question are:**

- Is this user same as on the host system or we should first write statement to create the user and then use it in the Dockerfile.
- If we defined random user without creating it, Does docker creates the user automatically.
- Should we refer UID of user or actual user string itself.
- When we get the interactive session in the terminal for the container, Does that session also has the privilege of USER defined in the Docker file and can't be switched to root user.

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake.  corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Docker container is an isolated environment.  It doesn't know about the host user in any meaningful way.  The container has its own `/etc/passwd` file, for example, which maps names to numeric user IDs.

The other important conceptual note is that, for most practical purposes, there's no need to "create a user".  If you `docker run -u 12345` a container with an arbitrary numeric uid, things will probably work fine even though you haven't formally "created the user" and it doesn't have an entry in `/etc/passwd`.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Dockerfile `USER` specifies a numeric uid, or a user name in the image's `passwd` file.  It's not related to a host user, though it's possible for the numeric uids to coincidentally match.  It's not a good practice to build an image specific to a single host user.
2. If you say `USER 12345` nothing in particular happens to "create the user", but you'll still be working in a context where for example **getuid**(2) returns 12345 and files will be owned by that numeric uid.
3. If you've previously `RUN adduser` to create a user, using its name in a `USER` statement is clearer.  (And it's slightly better practice to let the system choose the numeric uid than to specify it yourself; maybe create a "system" user.)
4. Interactive sessions in terminals aren't a critical use case for Docker IMHO.  Any work you do in this terminal will be lost as soon as the container exits.  You're in the isolated container environment, working as the container user, limited to the container filesystem; you cannot see the host files or host username.  Some Dockerfiles choose to give unrestricted passwordless sudo privilege to their "non-root" user and then you could freely `sudo` commands in this shell; I'd suggest not installing `sudo` at all.